# ADB and Activity Manager Problems

Tags: android-activity, adb

have read with adb Activity Manager the Activity from the App for Launcher on my Galaxy S2.

I start ADB Logcat on my Windows PC and launch the App on my Device, then i can see which Activity started exactly.

Now i have a new Device, an Galaxy S3. And i try the same adb logcat on this device, the activity manager dont show an activity from the app and show only pid, uid from the app but not more name of activity?

the driver of the device is correctly installed and device is rooted.

Why i can not see about adb logcat the activity from the application?

Sorry for my english. :)

Greetz